# Как вывести из каждой кнопки текст в отдельный блок?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
У меня есть HTML-код:

```
<div class="form__top">
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Тип сделки</span>
     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Аренда</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="arenda">Текст1</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="arenda2">Текст2</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="Vasileostrovskiy">Текст3</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Район</span>
     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Аренда</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="arenda">Текст4</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="arenda2">Текст5</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="Vasileostrovskiy">Текст6</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Метро</span>

     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Выберите вариант</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="Shodnenskay">Текст7</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="Tushinskay">Текст8</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-value="Kitay-gorod">Текст9</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>  

<!-- Tags -->
<ul class="form__tags">
  <li class="form__tags-text">
    <span class="form__tags-sdelka tags">Текст 0</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form__tags-text">
    <span class="form__tags-rayon tags">Текст 0</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form__tags-text">
    <span class="form__tags-metro tags">Текст 0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Код CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.form {

  margin-top: -110px;

  &__wrap {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 30px 35px 30px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow:0px 7px 13px 0px rgba(25,21,21,0.5);
  }

  &__top {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 -15px 35px;
  }
  
  &__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 15px;

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 260px;
  }

  &__text {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  &__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__input {
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gainsborough);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
  }

  &__input-square,
  &__input-price {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117px;
  }

  &__input-square:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 11px;
  }

  &__price {
    position: relative;

    span {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 19px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 12px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

  }

  &__input-price {
    max-width: 117px;
    padding-left: 32px;
  }

  &__price:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 11px;
  }

  &__bottom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  &__tags-text {
    color: var(--color-dull-gray);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 140%;
    background-color: var(--color-gainsborough);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  &__tags-close {
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &__tags-text:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  &__button {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  &__btn-filtr {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: var(--color-dull-gray);
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  &__btn-reset {
    color: var(--color-dull-gray);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-dull-gray);
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  &__btn-apply {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: var(--color-cornflower-blue);
  }

  // !!!!!!!!!
  &__select-wrap {
    position: relative;
  }

  &__select-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--color-dull-gray);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 19px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gainsborough);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 12px;
    position: relative;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background-image: url(../img/icon/icon-arrow.svg);
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 6px;
      pointer-events: none;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
  }

  &__select-list {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-gainsborough);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  &__select-list.active {
    display: block;
  }

  &__select-item{
    color: var(--color-dull-gray);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &__select-text,
  &__select-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  &__select-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-cornflower-blue);
    color: #fff;
  }

  &__select-item:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  }

  &__select-item:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  }

  &__select-input-hidden {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Код JavaScript:

```
 // DropDown
const formSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.form__select');

  formSelects.forEach(item => {

    const formSelectList = item.querySelector('.form__select-list');
    const formSelectTexts = item.querySelectorAll('.form__select-item');
    const formSelectBtn = item.querySelector('.form__select-text'); 
    const formSelectInputHidden = item.querySelector('.form__select-input-hidden');

    formSelectBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      formSelectList.classList.toggle('active');
    })
    
    formSelectTexts.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const targetText = e.target.textContent;
        formSelectBtn.textContent = targetText;
        formSelectInputHidden.value = e.target.dataset.value;
        formSelectList.classList.remove('active');
      })
   })
  
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== formSelectBtn) {
      formSelectList.classList.remove('active');
    }
    })

    });

const formTagsList = document.querySelector('.form__tags');
const formSelectText = document.querySelectorAll('.form__select-item');

  formSelectText.forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let targetText = e.target.textContent;

    let itemText = `
    <li class="form__tags-text">
        <span class="form__tags-sdelka tags">${targetText}</span>
      </li>
      <li class="form__tags-text">
        <span class="form__tags-sdelka tags">${targetText}</span>
      </li>
      <li class="form__tags-text">
        <span class="form__tags-sdelka tags">${targetText}</span>
      </li>
      `
    formTagsList.innerHTML = itemText;
    })

  })
```

Весь код на Codepen - https://codepen.io/Power2021/pen/QWgEwgP.

Сам собственно вопрос?
Не получается вывести из каждой кнопки текст.
Мне нужно сделать, что бы текст из каждой кнопки выводился в определенный блок, но у меня только выводиться один текст из каждой кнопки, во все три блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что при каждом нажатии ты перезаписываешь весь блок `form__tags`, а нужно перезаписывать только нужное поле

добавь дата атрибут к каждому итему на который нажимаешь, и по этому значению найдешь нужное поле и заменишь в нем текст

```
<div class="form__top">
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Тип сделки</span>
     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Аренда</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="sdelka" data-value="arenda">Текст1</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="sdelka" data-value="arenda2">Текст2</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="sdelka" data-value="Vasileostrovskiy">Текст3</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Район</span>
     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Аренда</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="rayon" data-value="arenda">Текст4</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="rayon" data-value="arenda2">Текст5</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="rayon" data-value="Vasileostrovskiy">Текст6</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form__item">
     <span class="form__text">Метро</span>

     <div class="form__select">
       <div class="form__select-wrap">
         <button class="form__select-text">Выберите вариант</button>
         <ul class="form__select-list">
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="metro" data-value="Shodnenskay">Текст7</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="metro" data-value="Tushinskay">Текст8</li>
           <li class="form__select-item" data-type="metro" data-value="Kitay-gorod">Текст9</li>
         </ul>
         <input class="form__select-input-hidden" type="text" value="">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

и изменения в обработчике

```
const formTagsList = document.querySelector('.form__tags');
const formSelectText = document.querySelectorAll('.form__select-item');

  formSelectText.forEach(item => {

  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let targetText = e.target.textContent;
    const type = e.target.dataset.type
    const tag = formTagsList.querySelector(`.form__tags-${type}`)
    
    
    tag.innerHTML = targetText;
    })

  })
```

названия переменных подбери на свое усмотрение

Comment: если помог отметь ответ как правильный и стрелку вверх)

Comment: Спасибо большое!